# Clarification about WPF Styles

Tags: wpf

In the below code, why might the first example fail to set the background to Blue, but, the second example work as one might expect they both would – that is, is sets the background to Blue?  Interestingly, when the style is applied in the second example, even though the BorderThickness is not specified in the Style, the property value of "3" also gets picked up, presumably because the new Style does not set it at all.

Code 1:

```
<GroupBox Margin="4,12,4,4"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="3"
                  Header="{x:Static res:UIResources.DepreciationText}"
                  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MainControlBorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="3"
                  Background="Blue" />
```

Code 2:

```
<GroupBox Margin="4,12,4,4"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="3"
                  Header="{x:Static res:UIResources.DepreciationText}"
                  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MainControlBorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="3">
                <GroupBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Blue" />
                </Style>
             </GroupBox.Style>
       </GroupBox>
```

You could reason from the above observation that the following are true:

1)  Some Style is getting applied to the GroupBox further up the tree – perhaps even to some base class of GroupBox, such as Control, since a search for a Style targeting GroupBox was not found.

2)  A property set on a control instance will not override the same property set in a Style targeting the control.

3)  There is not a way to augment an inherited Style, other than using the BasedOn property.  Using the BaseOn property implies you must know the Key of the Style you would like to base it on, unless, if you want to use BasedOn with a Style applied to a Type, you could somehow specify that – perhaps using the Type name in BasedOn?

Can anyone confirm or correct the above assertions, and whether they correctly explain the observed result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any sort of theme pack for your application that restyles controls?  My guess would be that you have a style somewhere overriding the control template in such a way that the Background property is completely ignored.  If the control template doesn't contain a `{TemplateBinding Background}`, the Background property does nothing.

You can definitely override properties by setting them explicitly, even if they are also set in a style.

By setting the style yourself without using a BasedOn, it implicitly uses the default control template for the GroupBox, rather than resolving to a style imported with your resources.  If you wanted to use the imported resource style, you could do this:

```
<Style TargetType="GroupBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

I suspect this would give you the same result as in the first case, as now you would be inheriting the offending control template that ignores your Background value.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer Dan.  The app is a monster app using multiple packages, including Infragistics.  There is theming going on, but I have not fully explored the mechanism.  Part of the problem is discovering the source styles, which may even be compiled away.  It sounds like I would need to review all Styles that apply to base types of GroupBox as well, such as Control, to find all Styles impacting GroupBox.

Comment: @Bill, I've definitely seen third-party theme packs that impose a fixed color scheme and ignore a lot of the properties that customize visualization.  This is particularly common when you have a setup that allows the user to select their preferred theme, as now you would rarely want to set the color explicitly, since you want it to be defined by the theme.

Comment: Yes, your point is well taken and I have seen a couple as well.  The odd thing here, however, is that the reason I needed to look into this is because the GroupBox is not changing its colors following the theme selection.  Also, I think some "themed control suites" rename any control where they override the standard control template, leaving the standard controls, well, standard;  I think that that is probably the better practice.